# How can I remotely deploy a rich client in .Net?

Tags: deployment, browser, client

Currently we run our web applications on a thin client browser IE 6 and it is slow.
We are a non-profit organization. All our offices are linked via VPN.
Opera 10 browser allows one to convert one's PC into a server.
I am thinking of deploying our application and Opera 10 on every client, meaning that the every client would run a server which in turn would run our application. 
Therefore, the clients would connect only to our database. This would speed things up.
However, I would need to deploy updates to our application from time to time.
How can I deploy a web application to the clients PC's remotely?

Our app is .Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [click-once deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx) which can handle auto-updating applications (I believe however, they should be .Net based)